# Activate / Desactivate layers on leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, controls, leaflet

I couldn't find any function to activate / desactivate layers ( overlayMaps ) when you click a button.

For example, I'm trying to make a zoom and activate (display) all the layers when a user clicks a button.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet does not have a concept of active versus inactive layers: you can do one of two things:

- Make the layer invisible with [setOpacity(0)](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setopacity) and visible with setOpacity(1)
- Use [removeLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-removelayer) to remove it, and `addTo` or `addLayer` to add it back.

The latter option is better, because it won't load tiles from the inactive layer. This is what the Leaflet layer control does as well behind the scenes.